# How to ask turtles to turn at the intersection point of patches where turtles are arriving from three direction

Tags: netlogo

I have created roads (gray patches) on which people (turtles) are randomly moving. At the intersection point (white patches) I am making them (turtles) to may or may not turn their headings. In the way I coded, if their headings are 90 and 270 it is working fine. But if heading is 0 almost 95% of the times they turn back (180) instead of turning to left(270) or right(90). There is no error in the code. I just simply want to know, can we code in some other way so that 0 heading turtles can also have 50% of chances for all the three turns like the other two headings.

Following is my code:

```
breed [people person]
globals [ streets intersections head]
people-own [ speed direction]
patches-own [ intersection? ]

to setup
   clear-all
   ask patches [set pcolor green
                set intersection? false]
   setup-street
   setup-people
end

to setup-street
  ;set streets patches with [ (( pxcor < max-pxcor and pxcor > min-pxcor ) ;and (pycor = 4) or (pxcor = 0 and ( pycor > min-pycor and pycor < 4))]

  set streets patches with [ (( pxcor < max-pxcor and pxcor > min-pxcor ) and (pycor = 4 or pycor = 5)) or ((pxcor = 0 or pxcor = 1) and ( pycor > min-pycor and pycor < 4))]

  set intersections patches with [ (pxcor = 0 or pxcor = 1) and (pycor = 4 or pycor = 5)]

   ask streets [set pcolor gray]
   ask intersections [ set pcolor white]
   setup-intersection
end

to setup-intersection
     ask intersections [ set intersection? true]
end

to setup-people
   ask n-of No-of-person patches with [ pcolor = gray or pcolor = white] [
     sprout-people 1 [
           set color brown
           set size 1
           set shape "person"
           set speed 0.01 + random-float 0.9
           set direction random 2
           set-default-headings direction
      ]
   ]
end

to set-default-headings [ direct]
   if direct = 0 [
     ;ask people with [ ( pxcor < max-pxcor and pxcor > min-pxcor ) and  pycor = 4 ]
     ask people with [ (pxcor < max-pxcor and pxcor > min-pxcor ) and (pycor  = 4 or pycor = 5)]
      [ set head random 2
          if head = 0 [ set heading 90]
          if head = 1 [ set heading 270]
      ]
    ]

   if direct = 1 [
   ;ask people with [ pxcor = 0 and ( pycor > min-pycor and pycor < 4) ]
     ask people with [(pxcor = 0 or pxcor = 1) and ( pycor > min-pycor and pycor < 4)]
      [ set head random 2
          if head = 0 [ set heading 0]
          if head = 1 [ set heading 180]
      ]
   ]
 end

 to go
    ask people [ fd speed 
                 check-intersection
                 check-end]
 end

 to check-intersection
      if intersection? [
           if heading = 90 [if random 20 < 10 [ set heading 180] ]
           if heading = 270 [if random 20 < 10 [ set heading 180] ]
           if heading = 0 [ let new-heading random 2
                         if (new-heading = 0) [rt 90 ]
                         if (new-heading = 1) [lt 90 ] ]
           ]
  end

  to check-end
      ask people [ if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = green [set heading  [heading] of self - 180 ] ]
  end
```

Comment: Please suggest some ideas. I will be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code with the speed slowed down and a single person created. I don't think the problem is your random direction creation - it is that the speed means that the person spends multiple ticks on the intersection and only leaves when the random direction generated moves them down again. For example, the agent enters the intersection with a heading of 0 and gets random heading 90 so moves to the right by some distance < 1 (from speed) and IS STILL IN THE INTERSECTION, so gets a new random heading say 90, still in intersection, then gets 270 so still in intersection and then gets 180 so leaves.

One way to fix this is to create a counter / flag. It gets set on reaching the intersection and the intersection is not checked if the flag is still set.

```
to go
  ask people [ fd speed
               set just-turned max (list 0 just-turned - 1) 
               check-intersection
               check-end]
end

to check-intersection
  if intersection? and just-turned = 0 [
       set just-turned 1 / speed + 1
       if heading = 90 [if random 20 < 10 [ set heading 180] ]
       if heading = 270 [if random 20 < 10 [ set heading 180] ]
       if heading = 0 [ let new-heading random 2
                     if (new-heading = 0) [rt 90 ]
                     if (new-heading = 1) [lt 90 ] ]
       ]
end
```

By the way, when I did this testing, I also noticed that at least some (and possibly all) agents created in the base of your T shaped streets have a heading of 45.

Also, some code suggestions, instead of things like

```
set head random 2
  if head = 0 [ set heading 0]
  if head = 1 [ set heading 180]
```

1/ you could use (so it doesn't check every if statement)

```
set head random 2
  ifelse head = 0 [ set heading 0] [ set heading 180]
```

2/ or (so you don't have to create the local variable for the random number)

```
set heading ifelse-value (random 2 = 0) [0] [180]
```

3/ or (so you can have different commands for different cases)

```
ifelse random 2 = 0 [ set heading 0] [ set heading 180]
```

4/ or (because the mathematical relationship exists in this case)

```
set heading random 2 * 180
```

Number 4 would be best in this case, but number 3 would also work for sections where you have different commands (like [lt 90][rt 90])

Comment: hi JenB I got your point and thanks for the code suggestions, but is their any solution out of my problem. If please help me.

Comment: sure, it's a logic problem though not a coding problem. You could solve it by making the agent move a full patch distance when it turns to that it gets out of the intersection but I think this is probably contrary to what you want to do with speed. I will modify my answer to do a better solution.

Comment: I am sorry to say but i am not getting the logic. Does variable Just-turned needs initialization? Among the value of just-turned and 0 max value will always be of just-turned so condition can never be true at intersection. Though i tried without any initialization and its running quite fine but i truly not getting how its working. Can you please make me understand. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it should be initialised (to 0, when the turtles are created) but I was lazy. This will work anyway, because NetLogo initialises automatically to 0, but good practice would have explicit coding for initialisation even if you want the value 0. The `max` is to deal with cases where 1/speed is not an integer - as you decrease by 1, then a non-integer won't ever get to 0 (eg it will be 0.5 then -0.5 then -1.5 etc).

Comment: Let's say the speed is 0.2, then 1/speed + 1 will be 6. For that turtle, it takes 5 ticks to completely cross the intersection (because the width of an intersection is 1 and it moves 0.2 per tick). But, because of the counter, once it has entered the intersection (and had the counter set), it won't check if it's on the intersection for 6 ticks, by which time it has got across.

Comment: one more thing need to know the persistence of value of global variable.

Comment: the value will be whatever you gave it at the start (by input control or in `set` in code) until you change it (by input control or `set`)

Comment: ask a separate question

Comment: Actually for the above interface i made intersection as the combination of 2 patches on both x-axis and y-axis.(all together 4-patches) and you said its of width 1. Is it an assumption or is there any specific rule on which we assume such width of patch. In the setting patch size is 13 pixel. I am confused of this pixel and patch relation...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83947/discussion-between-abha-trivedi-and-jenb).